# Open App Notification Setting and Turn Off Notification in Android 13 gives white screen and crash

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-13

I am facing an issue with Android 13. I have a button and click on that button I want to open the **App Notification Setting** and can Turn the ON/OFF notification there. It works fine below Android 13 but for Android 13 If I Turn OFF the notification and come back to my Android Application screen it gives a white screen and some of the UI elements disappear (Mainly those are API resposne based). Please help

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, activity.packageName)
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have a similar problem, but only if I “disable notifications”, the application “reboots”. It takes a long time to happen, that’s why there are complaints

Answer (score -1):

The process is terminated when runtime permissions are turned off.

Check for
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#app_process_terminates_when_permission_revoked

That's a policy when runtime permission is released, so you can find similar phenomena in other apps

So when going to settings, it would be a good idea to end the current activity and move or check the splash screen start logic

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)